# Best way to store Http Response in Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I was wondering what the best way was to store common action Http return types in an Enum. I am intending on using this towards my controllers. Any help is appreciated.

```
public enum Types
{
   BadResponse("Failed to load")
   NotFound()
   Ok()
   etc...
}
```

Comment: why not use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, or why you're doing this.

Comment: Enums aren't containers for methods.  What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: the idea is that I would like to reuse, lets say, NotFound("Sorry not found") and Notfound(). Reuse it within all my controllers

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating your own enum, you can use the Microsoft `HttpStatusCode` enum that comes with .NET.

You can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Hi Oscar, the idea is that I would like to reuse, lets say, NotFound("Sorry not found") and Notfound(). Reuse it within all my controllers

Comment: @ChrisH. could you please explain how `NotFound("Sorry not found")` is related to the question which asks about enums?

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to create diffrenet classes instead of enums. such as

```
class MyBaseStatusCods{}
class BadResponse:MyBaseStatusCods{}
class NotFound:MyBaseStatusCods{}
```

let me know if it helps.
thanks